# NuGet packages Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging are not working together

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I created a new Android project in Visual Studio for Mac and I installed the NuGet packages Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging.
But I get the following error if I use the NuGet packages Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging in my Android project:

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin/32.0.476/tools/Xamarin.Android.D8.targets(5,5): Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: /Users/myname/.nuget/packages/xamarin.google.guava.listenablefuture/1.0.0.5/buildTransitive/net6.0-android31.0/…/…/jar/guava-listenablefuture.jar : com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.class

I don’t get the error when I only use Xamarin.Forms in my Android project or
if I only use Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging in my Android project.

I use Visual Studio for Mac 2022 17.4 (build 2406).

How can I use the NuGet packages Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging together in my Android project?

[image]

Comment: You should not be using your Firebase packages in your SCL libraries, You need to use DependencyServices to access native code

Comment: What is wrong with my Android project?

Comment: From your question, I believe you are adding firebase DLLs into your shared project and that's not what you are supposed to do

Comment: It's not a shared project. I created an Android project in VS for Mac. Then I installed the NuGet packages.

Comment: That will not work. How are you planning on coding your UI? There are TWO different ways to use Xamarin. One is `Xamarin.Android`. This is regular "Android" coding, but using c# instead of java or kotlin. See [User Interfaces with Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/). The second is `Xamarin.Forms`.  An example: [Create a stacklayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/tutorials/stacklayout/?tabs=vsmac&tutorial-step=1). This is what I describe in my answer. Which approach will you use?

Comment: I use the MonoGame Android template to create the Android project and I create a Shared Code project. Then I add a project reference in the Android project to the Shared Code project and then I install all the Xamarin NuGet packages in the Android project so that I can use Xamarin in my projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/issues/535

It seems to work now. I installed Xamarin.Google.Guava Version="31.1.0.4" and then I installed Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging and finally Xamarin.Forms. In addition, it was necessary to add this line to my .csproj file:

```
<XamarinGoogleGuavaOptOut>true</XamarinGoogleGuavaOptOut>
```

Answer (score 0):

What "project template" did you use to create this?

If you didn't choose a "Xamarin.Forms" template, then you won't succeed in adding Xamarin.Forms.

- Start over, and choose Xamarin.Forms / Blank App. Build. You should see MULTIPLE projects in your solution: a cross-platform one (that references Xamarin.Forms nuget), and an Android one.
- Add Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging to the Android project.

The end result is that Xamarin.Forms nuget is part of cross-platform code, the Android implementation of XFM is part of Android code.

These are two separate projects; it is not meaningful to have both nugets in a single project.

- Now, when you build the app for Android, it will include the cross-platform project correctly.

Comment: I used the MonoGame Android template to create my project and currently I have only this project in my solution.

Comment: Then why do you need Xamarin Forms in there if you are not using Shared code ?